# my application is crashed due to thread use how can i fix it

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm using thread `onClick` method. It run successfully but after while crashed. I did not know why ... put the code is here

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // invisible first image
            // imgVScrub.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imgMoveCream.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // translate the particle by anim

            forCreamAnim.start();
            // imgVTemp.startAnimation(creamParticleAnim);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // : handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        // back animation of cream
                        imgVScrub.startAnimation(showerBackRotateAnimCream);

                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

and log trace is here

```
05-27 04:30:29.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1682): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-90
05-27 04:30:29.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1682):   android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
05-27 04:30:29.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1682):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
05-27 04:30:29.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1682):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:722)
05-27 04:30:29.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1682):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:771)
05-27 04:30:29.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1682):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4005)
05-27 04:30:29.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1682):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8576)
05-27 04:30:29.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1682):     at android.view.View.startAnimation(View.java:12980)
05-27 04:30:29.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1682):     at dwt.wasif.manicure.CreamActivity$1$1.run(CreamActivity.java:102)
05-27 04:30:29.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1682):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: you are updating ui from a thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start your animation in ui thread..all the ui related changes need to be done in ui thread

use below code

```
ActiviyName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() { 

        // back animation of cream 
         imgVScrub.startAnimation(showerBackRotateAnimCream); 

    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. replace your finally block by this code

```
finally { 

YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override 
        public void run() { 

            // back animation of cream 
             imgVScrub.startAnimation(showerBackRotateAnimCream); 

        } 
    }); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call startAnimation() from within a background thread.

Android only allows you to do UI things on the... UI thread. You're currently calling `imgVScrub.startAnimation(showerBackRotateAnimCream);` from a Runnable in a background thread, which is raising this error.

Simply move your animation start into normal, UI thread code.

Answer (score 0):

Move  `imgVScrub.startAnimation(showerBackRotateAnimCream);` in your main thread.

If you want to perform Ui related task on background then you have to call runOnUiThread(),which will make things complicated.So call  `imgVScrub.startAnimation(showerBackRotateAnimCream);` in your main thread.